# Equivalent of below xaml in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a CompositeCommand called NavigateCommand in my Infrastructure Project. I pass parameters to a method using below mentioned XAML:

```
Command="{x:Static inf:ApplicationCommands.NavigateCommand}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding ListSourcePage}"
```

Now, I want to do the same using C#. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that code below is in the class, where `ListSourcePage` property is declared:

```
if (ApplicationCommands.NavigateCommand.CanExecute(ListSourcePage))
{
    ApplicationCommands.NavigateCommand.Execute(ListSourcePage);
}
```